# Problema com fullscan do youtube em site no Adobe Muse

Tags: html5

Bom dia!
Estou desenvolvendo um site responsivo através do Adobe Muse.
O site está baseado em 5 break points (1200px-1000px-800px-600px-400px) e tem saído muito bem em diversas telas que testei.

Estou com problemas apenas em uma página de vídeos que inclui. Através do proprio youtube usei o iframe que eles disponibilizam na opção de compartilhar. No layout maior, de 1200px pra cima, tudo funciona normal, o vídeo carrega, é responsivo e o tela cheia cobre toda a tela. Mas, quando são acionados qualquer um dos pontos a partir do 1000px o tela cheia trava.

Ele tenta entrar no modo, mas quando a tela preenche parece que ele tenta entrar num break point maior, como se entendesse que o modo tela cheia na verdade é uma tela maior. E nisso, ou volta pra pagina como se tivesse dado um atualizar, ou trava o navegador.

Alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecendo? Quais códigos preciso postar para entenderem melhor?

o site para poderem testar e entender melhor: sendrock.com.br
Eu desabilitei por enquanto o botão do tela cheia, mas se voces diminuirem a largura do navegador e dar um duplo clique em qualquer vídeo o problema vai ocorrer.

Obrigado!

EDIT:

estou esperando propagar algumas mudanças que fiz na minha hospedagem, criei esse site de teste na 000 só pra vcs poderem ver o erro que ocorre.

app-1524837397.000webhostapp.com

Na aba vídeos, tentem executar o tela cheia do youtube num celular ou fechando a tela do navegador para menos de 1000px

Comment: Cara seu site não está carregando. está uma página em branco tanto no FF quanto no Chrome

Comment: Desculpe, estou fazendo uma alteração nele e ja ja esta no ar de volta. Aviso quando estiver ok